# Redirect to our custom 404 page fir links to disabled store view

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, 404-page

I disabled one of my store views, and now if I type the url to the disabled store view, Magento displays the default 404 page (coming from errors/default/404.phtml)

I want to redirect to our custom (CMS) 404 page, like any other non-existing url.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes its possible you can try the .htaccess redirection rules.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone bumps into the same issue, the way I ended up solving this:

Override `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php` by copying  it to `app/code/local/` and then in `function preDispatch` around line `480` (Magento 1.9.3)

change:

`// Prohibit disabled store actions
if (Mage::isInstalled() && !Mage::app()->getStore()->getIsActive()) {
    Mage::app()->throwStoreException();
}`

to

`// Redirect disabled store actions to 404 page
if (Mage::isInstalled() && !Mage::app()->getStore()->getIsActive()) {
    // Set store to default non-disabled store view
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('he');
    // forward to our custom 404 page
    $this->_forward('noRoute','index','cms');
}`

Hopes that helps anyone :)